# Best practice for modifying storyboard auto layout constraints in code?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uistoryboard

I've always done my UIs in code but have decided that I should use storyboards and auto layout for a current project. Everything had been going well until I built a complex scene with about 50 views with lots of hierarchy and some grid of views.

The problem is that my auto layout is getting muddled on some devices and orientations. I'm finding it challenging to use IB to try fixing the dozens (hundreds?) of constraints or to track down the problems and resolve them. The situation is such that I'm not getting errors or warnings, just some unpleasant layouts at times. And IB can be a pain with all the clicking and changing settings you need to do to track down constraint information, let alone get a full idea of how they all relate in a scene.

I've just spent a day reading docs and background material on auto layout and constraints and it seems my best solution is to use the visual format to specify constraints in code and create some custom code to help. However, I can't seem to find anything on how to make the transition from IB to code.

Specifically, should I wipe all IB constraints and do them all by hand or is it possible to be selective? I ask because I have some groups of views in containing views where the content views have a perfect layout.

Secondly, where best do I put my code? I want to coexist storyboards and just want to selectively modify some complex scenes. Is a view controller's viewWillAppear: the right place to modify or remove/add constraints for the view it controls?

Comment: Just an quick update, I have not yet resolved this issue. I do a lot of freelance work and had to shift this aside for a bit, but hope to get back to it in a day or so and try the different suggestions. Thanks to Ron and Eagle11 for their suggestions, both of which seem very good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry to take so so long to get back to this while other projects intruded.

I had to do a lot of refactoring to simplify my scenes so that auto layout could do the right thing, and yet I am not fully satisfied with the results. The problem seems to be that IB is just not easy to use with lots of items, and that auto layout is complicated, by necessity.

With that said, the best results I've seen so far are drawn from this article by Justin Driscoll: http://themainthread.com/blog/2014/02/building-a-universal-app.html

He advocates building custom views to encapsulate reusable UI components. I have taken this approach but have extended the idea to also bundle up related components that are not going to layout very differently as the layout changes. For example, I have a progress bar with button and two labels, so even though I am not reusing them as a group, they need to be adjacent and conceptually are related, so I've made a custom view for them which handles the auto layout as Justin suggests.

I'm now taking the approach that each level of auto layout should only have a handful of elements. If one level gets too complex, I'll bundle up some related items in a custom view and push some auto layout inside that new view. So far it isn't too bad.

Comment: I'm going to select this as the best answer as Justin's solution has given me the most control and caused the least number of problems. Ron and Eagle11 both gave excellent advice that led me to this answer and I wish I could check all three answers, but that isn't possible. Thanks folks.

Answer (score 9):

Connect an IBOutlet for the NSLayoutConstraint you want to be able to modify in the storyboard/xib file to your controller/view class.

Once you have the layout object connected, you can modify the .constant property and animate the view:

```
[self.containerView layoutIfNeeded]; //make sure all layout operations are done
self.containerViewBottomLayoutConstraint.constant = 200.0; //change the layout
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
    [self.containerView layoutIfNeeded]; //animate the changes
}];
```

updated: you can add your modification code in viewDidLoad, awakeFromNib, viewDidAppear, or event based. It really depends on your intentions.

Comment: I think I have way too many constraints to hook them up to IBOutlets, but if I can reduce my changes to a small set this might work. I need to study the problem a bit to decide, but it looks like a lot of work that might be easier if all constraints were in code to start with.

Comment: My intent is to fix the constraints so that they work in all device configurations. I'm not planning to animate them or change them on the fly if I can help it. I assume that viewWillAppear might be the place to set them up, but your comment makes me wonder if that is the right place. Does awakeFromNib fire when using Storyboards and is it the right place to remove/add constraints? Is viewDidLoad too late? Will it cause the scene to change when the user can see it?

Comment: awakeFromNib is indeed called when the view(controller) is deserialized from the storyboard: more info here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSObject_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/awakeFromNib
I'd setup the constraints in viewDidLoad or awakeFromNib, depending of your intention to do additional view hierarchy modifications in didLoad. What is the problem with actually setting up all constraints in the storyboard? Try the new beta xcode, it has a few improvements. Also check out the autolayout WWDC13 sessions..

Comment: Thanks, Ron. I'll check out the docs and watch the sessions again. My problem with doing it in IB is that once you have >100 constraints the amount of clicking and jumping around gets to be a pain and breaks concentration. And IB unfortunately doesn't seem to always maintain the state of the UI, so that when you return to something the menu or editor reverts to a default. IB has come a long way and I appreciate the complexity of the problem it is trying to address, but I find it much easier to name objects and group, order and organize them in code when I have this many entities.

Comment: Also, you never know if IB will do what you want when you pick an option like "add missing constraints" or "apply changes to constraints". It is good at pointing out errors but it is not nearly as expressive or specific as coding.

Answer (score 2):

Auto layout can be really tricky when using that many views. I have used similarly complex views structures, and I find that it is best to try to keep all of the constraints in code or in IB. Right now we are keeping them in IB. The only time that we move a constraint into code is when we are supporting a different screen size, and we need to modify a single constraint for the view to work right. I have always modified the constraints in viewDidLoad myself.

When something gets messed up I almost always have to nuke all of the constraints on that view and start over. It sucks, but it's often quicker than tracking down the problem. One thing that we do that makes it easier to deal with that sort of thing is to use .xibs along with your storyboard. That way, each view can handle it's own layout, and you can pull that into a view that is sitting in a storyboard.

Comment: I can believe that "all or nothing" is the right thing as the potential for mistakes seems high. 
Can you explain how you use xibs? Do you make one to replace a whole scene and load it from code?

Comment: Well, I'm sure we don't always do it the best way, but we have found a method that is working for us. 
We try to create all of the hierarchy within the storyboards, and depending on the circumstance we create the content within the storyboard as well. In some of our projects we have several storyboards because the project is very large. Because of this, we break of lot of our views out into xibs. We load the xib in code and set it to the view in the view controller.

Comment: BTW, autolayout gets easier to use after a week or so of dealing with all of the weird crap it does. Once you really get it figured out, it can be used fairly easily. Even on large projects.