# Autolayout - practical layout of complex screens and a conceptual hole

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode6

I'm trying hard to drink the Autolayout KoolAid in Xcode 6.  I understand the fundamentals.  It's solving a set of linear equations for the coordinates and sizes for all on-screen objects.  I've watch the videos and read the tutorials.  I've gotten it to work.

With all the different devices and screen sizes out there, it seems like a great solution.

So here's a mock-up of my screen:

[image: simple screen mock-up]

When I create this simple layout of 5 labels (just the yellow ones for now), I need 20 constraints, right?  Height, width, X position and Y position - for each one.

So my constraint list ends up looking like this:

[image: constraint list]

First, I don't see the what that sort order is there, which makes it hard to find things.  Worse, that's already a massive number of constraints to look through to find problems.

This can't be a very complex screen in the big scheme of things. **What concept am I missing here?  What organizational method would help me?** If people are doing large screens with many elements, how are they managing the dozens and dozens of constraints?

Note: I don't want to use a table because that seems like overkill - I don't need to scroll, I don't need buttons in cells, and I don't really want to bother styling a table and cells to look like what I've got there in the mock up.  This is really just an example of 5 elements on a screen (15 on that screen, actually).

Comment: Someone with a similar crisis and hints at a solution. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22601947/3713234

Comment: You don't need height and width for labels since they have an intrinsic content size, so that would simplify things a little. Actually these kinds of constraints can be pretty compact in code, if you use the vfl; I personally like that better than a ton of constraints in IB. I don't think there is any bigger organizational principle you're missing here.

Comment: Are you sure you need to specify height and width of these labels? I use AutoLayout a lot, and I'm thinking you can do this with just leading and top constraints. The height and width will be sized as needed to accommodate the text displayed.

Comment: Also, I don't know why you think using a table view wold be overkill. I'm sure I could setup a table view like you would need faster than I could add all those constraints, and it gives you more flexibility. For instance, you could just return a larger height for the cells to spread things out on a larger screen.  It also leaves you with far fewer outlets.

Comment: For the most part, the old springs-and-struts model of the autoresizing mask has just as many details, but they don't appear in the document view of the NIB. Rather, they're implicit in the contents of the Size inspector. With auto layout, the size inspector shows constraints affecting the view being inspected. So, those details are still there. I recommend you put the constraints in the document view out of your mind (except when you need to refer to them there) and focus on the size inspector like you used to.

Comment: Good point about the height and width - but instead of five labels, just imagine five other kinds of elements.  Still a heap of constraints.  So cumbersome.   Autolayout seems to violate DRY quite a bit.  I've read others factor out into custom views whenever autolayout constraints get too numerous - I'll have to try that and see what constraints I can factor out into a UI class so that it behaves itself in a parent view.